# CRC32 checksums are different in Zlib Ruby and Python libraries

Tags: python, ruby, zlib, crc, crc32

I'm trying to generate CRC32 checksums in Ruby and Python for the same string and get different results.

Python

```
from zlib import crc32
x = "SheetJS"
crc32(x)
#=> -1647298270
```

NodeJS

```
var CRC32 = require('crc-32');
var x = "SheetJS";
CRC32.str(x); 
#=> -1647298270
```

Ruby

```
require 'zlib'
x = "SheetJS"
Zlib::crc32(x)
#=> 2647669026
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the same values, the difference is in the interpretation. Python and NodeJS interpret crc32 as a signed number, Ruby - as unsigned. Take a look:

```
In [1]: import struct

In [2]: struct.unpack('i', struct.pack('I', 2647669026))
Out[2]: (-1647298270,)
```

We are converting 2647669026 to bytes as unsigned integer, and then reading it as a signed one.